# Removing duplicate files

Tags: python, pdf, operating-system

I have a question.

I'm trying to remove a file when there are two the same, and I'm trying to remove the instance with xls in it. This is a duplicate file converted from xls to pdf.

[image]

I've tried the following code:

```
for x in os.listdir(target):
    if x.endswith('.html'):
        os.unlink(target + x)
    if x.endswith('.pdf'):
        x3 = x.replace('xls.pdf', '')
        x2 = x.replace('pdf', '')
        if x2 == x3 == True:
            os.unlink(target + "%s" % x3)
```

However, nothing happens unfortunately..

```
#Code implementation

for x in os.listdir(target):
    if x.endswith('.html'):
        os.unlink(target + x)
    if x.endswith('.pdf'):
        [ os.rename(x,re.sub(r"([0-9]{4}[0-9]+)[a-z]+",r"\1",x)) for x in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\Max12\Desktop\xml\pdfminer\UiPath\attachments\75090058\Status\Verwerking')]
```

Please help

doesn't work either:

```
from pathlib import Path
for x in os.listdir(target):
    if x.endswith('xls.pdf'):
        x5 = x.replace('xlss','')
        print(x5)
    for x where "xls" not in x:
            
    if x3 == x2 == True:
        print(x2)
        type(x2)
        for filename in Path(r"C:\Users\Max12\Desktop\xml\pdfminer\UiPath\attachments\75090058\Status\Verwerking").glob("*xls.pdf"):
                filename.unlink()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `Invoke Powershell` activity with the following script:

```
dir *xls.pdf | foreach{
  $baseName = $_.Name.replace("xls.pdf","")
  if(Test-Path "$($baseName).pdf") {
    #current file is a duplicate
    Remove-Item -Path "$($baseName)xls.pdf"
  }
}
```

It looks for all files that end in `xls.pdf`, sees if a `.pdf` version of that file exists. If it does, it removes the `xls.pdf` version of the file